# Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update. when install metronic theme in laravel 8

Tags: laravel

[image]php version is 8 bcoz this theme cant support php version less then 8

Answer (score 0):

Enable the fileinfo extension in your `php.ini` file.

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Then restart your server

Comment: i not found this line in my php.ini file,i use php version 8.0

Comment: You couldn't find fileinfo in your ini? If the extension is not enabled it would be commented with a colon (;)

Comment: extension=php_fileinfo.dll
this line not in my ini file then how i comment or uncomment that line

Comment: It should usually be there. If not you might need to download the extension manually and install it.

Comment: Xampp usually ships with all extensions. If the extension is in the extension folder (you could find that from the php.ini file). And generally you only have to uncomment the line